# All the Idempotent elements of a finite-dimensional algebra

Tags: representation-theory

Does there exist any way to determine whether or not, we have found all the idempotent elements of a finite-dimensional algebra A?

In other words, if A is a finite-dimensional algebra with generators {a,b,c,d} and some relations among them, can we find all the idempotent elemets of this algebra? And if you have a set of idempotent elements, how do we decide whether or not contains all the idempotent elemets?

Comment: This is already fairly delicate for, say, matrix algebras. Things get much nicer if you ask for the central idempotents, or as a special case require that $A$ is commutative.

Comment: So there does not exist any standard way to determine if you already have the full set of generators for a given algebra??

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "standard" and by "determine." (Also, I thought the question was about idempotents, not generators.) For matrix algebras you can write out the condition that $M^2 = M$ as an explicit set of quadratic equations in the entries of $M$. Does this count as "determining" the idempotents? There are other descriptions available as well, but whether they count as "determining" the idempotents depends on the intended application.

Comment: I understand your point, you are 100% right. For instance, in the above example of a four dimensional algebra with some relations among the generators in such abstract way, my question make any sense?

Comment: Well, there was another response saying this that got deleted: if you pick generators corresponding to a basis of $A$, you can write out the condition that $a^2 = a$ (where $a$ is an arbitrary element) as an explicit set of polynomial equations in the coefficients of $a$ wrt this basis, by repeatedly applying your relations until you end up with elements of your basis. Again, whether this counts as "determining" the idempotents depends on the intended application. Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: Maybe my last comment is more vague than the previous, but i have already found some idempotents. And i want to know if i have found all the idempotents of tha algebra. So i guess that i have to look on the relations between the generators to decide if i found every idempotent element right?

Comment: Given a 4-dimensional algebra A with generators, {1,a,b,c} and relations a^2=a, ab=b, ca=c , b^2=c^2=ba=ac=bc=cb=0. Can we find all the idempotents?

Comment: Yes, this computation seems pretty doable. Write an arbitrary element of the algebra as a linear combination of the generators, square that element, rewrite the square as a linear combination of the generators using the relations, then solve the resulting system of polynomials.